# DEleting Files when access is denied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013

I am having problems with Visual Studio such that something somewhere is not being deleted and my version of my SharePoint wsp / dll is not being loaded.  Instead Visual Studio is loading an old version so my changes are not happening.  SO I decided to remove all traces of the dll from my machine.  Unfortunately some of the locations of the dll are in  'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_393b5b
0e\ProjectAssemblies\tmutezl601\ShareManager.dll' and I get "Access to the path is denied".  Cleaning the solution does not work either.  What can I do to remove all of these dlls.  (There are lots copies of the dll littered across my hard drive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better try to solve the initial problem, i.e. why the new version of your DLL is not loaded.
If you updated (or desinstalled/reinstalled) your WSP, it automatically triggers an IIS pool recycling. This ensures the new version of the DLL will be loaded by the Web app the next time.
However, this restart does not happen for other processes that may be involved in SharePoint, like (mainly) the SharePoint Timer Windows service (owstimer). If your WSP contains a job or a workflow, the code runs in owstimer.exe. You thus need to manually restart the SharePoint Timer service after each WSP update (on all servers of the farm).